# Python Dataframe: Split Column Into Two Columns Based on (,) THEN Reformat Resulting Values

Tags: python, split, conditional-statements, rounding, nan

I have the following python data frame with one column --> CI_80.  I want to create "CI80_lb" and "CI80_ub" from "CI_80" column.

```
CI_80                                       CI80_lb CI80_ub
(12.963511423826183, 15.49103403071927)     13      15
(12.287835227023837, 14.312164772976164)    12      14
(-6.4272594546429325, 27.427259454642932)   n/a     27
(nan, nan)                                  nan     nan
(-19.369658165550526, 30.77319897730662)    n/a     31
```

Below is the logic I want to implement:

Step 1: Split CI_80 into two additional columns splitting on the comma (,)

a. below is the code I tried but it error out

```
df_adhoc_3['CI80_lowerbound'], df_adhoc_3['CI80_upperbound'] = zip(*df_adhoc_3['CI_80'].map(lambda x: x.split(',')))
```

*AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'*

Step 2: Round the numbers in the two created columns from the split

Step 3: If CI80_lb is negative have the column value equal to n/a

Step 4: If CI_80 equals (nan, nan) make the two created columns equal nan

Step 5: Remove parenthesis in columns

Comment: you can directly do this in step 1: `df_adhoc_3['CI80_lowerbound'], df_adhoc_3['CI80_upperbound'] = df_adhoc_3['CI_80']`

Comment: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" when I try your code above

Comment: can you print `df_adhoc_3` and show the output?

Answer (score 0):

Split is for taking portions of a string. Note that in a tuple, the comma and parentheses aren't actually part of the tuple, they're just part of how the tuple is formatted when it's displayed.  (Similarly, in the list `[1,2,3]`, there are no commas in the list, the commas are displayed just to separate the actual entries.) When you have a container such as a list or a tuple, you should use indexing. So:

```
def clean(data):
    lb,ub = data
    try:
       lb= int(round(lb))
       ub= int(round(ub))
    except:
       pass
    if lb < 0 :
       lb =np.nan
    return(lb,ub) 
df_adhoc_3['CI80_lowerbound'],df_adhoc_3['CI80_lowerbound']=
df_adhoc_3['CI80'].apply(clean)
```

Notes:

I'm not aware of a `n/a` in Python. If you want the string 'n/a', obviously you can replace the line `lb=np.nan` with `lb = 'n/a'`.

If both lb and ub are `nan`, then the try block will fail, and it will just return their original values (which is `nan`). It's not entirely clear what you want to do if only one is `nan`, or if there are other types of bad data, so you'll have to adjust if you want other behavior.

You didn't say, but I assumed that you want the numbers cast as integers after rounding.